# looping through two arrays and left join

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have two arrays, the first one contains stages of a workflow:

```
const workflow_stages = ["Draft", "Kick-Off", "Phase 1", "Phase 2", "Complete"];
```

The second one contains tasks for certain workflow stages:

```
const tasks = [{workflow_stage: "Kick-Off",
             tasks: ["Assignment1", "Assignment2", "Assignment3"]},
            {workflow_stage: "Phase 2",
             tasks: ["Phase2_Assignment1", "Phase2_Assigment2"]}]
```

How do I iterate through both these arrays and have a combined array where it lists out ALL of the workflow_stages (regardless if there are tasks) and their associated tasks (kind of like a left join):

```
const combined = [{workflow_stage: "Draft",
                tasks: []},
               {workflow_stage: "Kick-Off",
                tasks: ["Assignment1", "Assignment2", "Assignment3"]},
               {workflow_stage: "Phase 1",
                tasks: []},
               {workflow_stage: "Phase 2",
                tasks: ["Phase2_Assignment1", "Phase2_Assigment2"]},
               {workflow_stage: "Complete",
                tasks: []}]
```

Comment: can you make your code actually valid?

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is between "tasks" and "combined" - tasks looks the same as combined.

Comment: You just need to loop over workflow_stages and look if there's a task associated to it on the tasks variable, if not, return empty tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all tasks in an object and then map all `workflow_stage` with an object with stage and tasks.

```js
var workflow_stages = ['Draft', 'Kick-Off', 'Phase 1', 'Phase 2', 'Complete'],
    tasks = [{ workflow_stage: 'Kick-Off', tasks: ['Assignment1', 'Assignment2', 'Assignment3'] }, { workflow_stage: 'Phase 2', tasks: ['Phase2_Assignment1', 'Phase2_Assigment2'] }],
    collection = Object.create(null),
    result;

tasks.forEach(function (item) {
    collection[item.workflow_stage] = (collection[item.workflow_stage] || []).concat(item.tasks);
});

result = workflow_stages.map(function (workflow_stage) {
    return {
        workflow_stage: workflow_stage,
        task: collection[workflow_stage] || []
    };
});
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var workflow_stages = ['Draft', 'Kick-Off', 'Phase 1', 'Phase 2', 'Complete'],
    tasks = [{ workflow_stage: 'Kick-Off', tasks: ['Assignment1', 'Assignment2', 'Assignment3'] }, { workflow_stage: 'Phase 2', tasks: ['Phase2_Assignment1', 'Phase2_Assigment2'] }],
    collection = new Map,
    result;

workflow_stages.forEach(workflow_stage => collection.set(workflow_stage, { workflow_stage, tasks: [] }));

tasks.forEach(({ workflow_stage, tasks }) => collection.get(workflow_stage).tasks.push(...tasks));

result = [...collection.values()];
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` and `array#find`. Iterate through `workflow_stages` array and for each value check for the object in the `tasks` array. If the object exists return the object otherwise create a new object and return it.

```js
var workflow_stages = ['Draft', 'Kick-Off', 'Phase 1', 'Phase 2', 'Complete'],
    tasks = [{ workflow_stage: 'Kick-Off', tasks: ['Assignment1', 'Assignment2', 'Assignment3'] }, { workflow_stage: 'Phase 2', tasks: ['Phase2_Assignment1', 'Phase2_Assigment2'] }],
    result = workflow_stages.map(workflow_stage => {
        var task = tasks.find(o => o['workflow_stage'] === workflow_stage);
        return task ? task : {workflow_stage, tasks : []};
    });
    
console.log(result);
```